# Typescript module export not work when import something

Tags: javascript, typescript, powerbi

I trying to create PowerBI custom visual and i must use typescript for that. I'm not too familiar with typescript. So I got 2 ts files under same namespace(I using VS Code editor):

visual.ts

```
module powerbi.extensibility.visual {

export class Visual implements IVisual {
    private target: HTMLElement;
    private updateCount: number;

    constructor(options: VisualConstructorOptions) {
        console.log('Visual constructor', options);
        this.target = options.element;
        this.updateCount = 0;
    }

    public update(options: VisualUpdateOptions) {

        console.log('Visual update', options);
        console.log(testFunc());
        $('#datepicker').datepicker();

        this.target.innerHTML = `<p>Update count:     <em>${(this.updateCount++)}</em></p>`;
    }

    public destroy(): void {
        //TODO: Perform any cleanup tasks here
    }
  }
}
```

test.ts

```
import React=require('react');
import ReactDOM=require('react-dom');

module powerbi.extensibility.visual {

  export function testFunc():String{

      return "Test string";
  }

  export class TestClass{}
}
```

Problem is when there is no imports in test.ts i can see and use exported function "testFunc()"(VS Code see that function) but when i add imports i cant user that function(also VS Code don't recognize that function)? Is there any way to have imports and to use that function?

Comment: trying changing imports to `import * as React from 'react'`, `import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'`.

Comment: its not working